# How to get rid of 500 Internal Server Error using Python and Flask?

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I am getting an Internal Server Error on my website. When you go to the results page it'll throw the 500 Internal Server Error. I am not really sure why. It says I am getting a "KeyError: 'test'".

Here is the code in Python:

```
 @app.route('/results/')
def results():
    votes = {}
    for f in poll_data['fields']:
        votes[f] = 0

    f  = open(file, 'r+')
    for line in f:
        voted = line.rstrip("\n")
        votes[voted] += 1
        

    return render_template('results.html', data=poll_data, votes=votes)
```

And here is the "KeyError:" I am getting:
[image]

Here is some more code:

```
file = 'data0.txt'

 
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', data = poll_data)

@app.route('/poll')
def poll():
    vote = request.args.get('field')

    out = open(file, 'a+')
    out.write( vote + '\n' )
    out.close() 

    return render_template('thankyou.html', data = poll_data)

@app.route('/results/')
def results():
    votes = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for f in poll_data['fields']:
        votes[f] = 0

    f  = open(file, 'r+')
    for line in f:
        vote = line.rstrip("\n")
        votes[vote] += 1
        

    return render_template('results.html', data=poll_data, votes=votes)

@app.route('/contact/')
def contact():
    return render_template('contact.html')

@app.route('/helpfullinks/')
def helpfullinks():
    return render_template('helpfullinks.html')
    



 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: It would appear that inside your file is a line which is `test` and that is not a value inside `poll_data['fields']`

Comment: inside of `file = 'data0.txt'`  ??

Comment: Yes, in that file.

Comment: @Nick, thats weird because there is nothing in the file named test.

Comment: @Nick, it works fine on my prototype server (127.0.0.1:500) but when I run it on my actual server and domain i get an error.

Comment: Weird indeed, based on the code you have shared the `vote` values which are used as indexes (and hence the `'test'` value) can only come from that file. Are you sure the copy of the file on the actual server is the same as on your prototype?

Comment: That doesn't really help, all I can see is the Internal Server error message.

Answer (score 0):

The problem according to your screenshot is that `votes` does not have a key as the value of `voted`. If you change `votes` to be - `votes=Counter()` or `votes=defaultdict(int)` (both imported from collections that's should solve it)

Comment: Hey Tom, I tried to change votes to votes=defaultdict(int) . However, the error did not go away. I added more of my code to the original post to see if there was an error somewhere else. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a hunch without more information but I bet the problematic line is this

```
voted = line.rstrip("\n")
votes[voted] += 1
```

As written the votes dictionary is populated from a different dataset, poll_data, than the one used to accumulate votes, "file". If a key exists in "file" that does not exist in poll_data you would expect to see the error you've written.

Based on this snippet you might benefit from the defaultdict in the collections module.

Add

```
import collections
```

Replace

```
votes = {}
for f in poll_data['fields']:
    votes[f] = 0
```

With

```
votes = collections.defaultdict(int)
```

The default dictionary will allow you retrieve values where no key exists which is what your code does with the `+=` operator. In the case the default dictionary defaults the key value to the int function output which is zero.